# "Cannot assign value of type 'AuthDataResult?' to type 'User?' and Value of type 'AuthDataResult' has no member 'uid'

Tags: swift

I have problem in line`currentUser = user`  which is  cannot assgin value of type AuthDataResult?' to type User
currentUserId = (user?.uid)! -> Value of type AuthDataResult has no member uid
I could not figure how to implement the AuthDataResult in it. Please help
Thanks

```
class AuthFirebase: NSObject {
    //This is instance of FIRDatabase to read and write data from Firebase database
    static let dataBase = Database.database().reference()
    static var currentUserID:String = ""
    static var currentUser: User? = nil
    //Create Function to Log In
    static func LogIn(email:String, password:String, completion: @escaping(_ success: Bool ) ->
        Void) {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion:{ (user,error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(false)
            }
            else {
                currentUser = user
                currentUserID = (user?.uid)!
                completion(true) }

        })

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have understood it wrong, the `completion handler` is returning `AuthDataResult?` and `Error`. To get the value of `user`, you have to do this:

```
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: collectionTF[0].text!, password: collectionTF[1].text!, completion: { (authDataResult, error) in

                if let error = error
                {
                   print(error)

                }
                else
                {
                    if let user = authDataResult?.user { //This is the user 
                    currentUser = user
                    currentUserId = user.uid

                    completion(true)
                   }
                }
}
```

This is how you can get the `User` from `AuthDataResult`.

Comment: Thank I Understand now

Comment: @LanNguyen You're welcome. Mark it as correct, so that future people can rely on this answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I modified the code and it worked fine. However, Xcode run error on this issue again at currentUser=user line. as. Cannot assign value of Type User to type User?

```
 static func LogIn(email:String, password:String, completion: @escaping(_ success: Bool ) ->
        Void) {
        Auth.auth().signIn (withEmail: email, password: password, completion:{ (AuthDataResult,error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(false)
            }
            else {
                if let user = AuthDataResult?.user {
                currentUser = user << cannot assign value of type"User to type"User?'
                currentUserID = user.uid
                completion(true) }
            }



    }
)

}
}
```

Comment: Look at the type of `currentUser`, it's of type `User?` and not `User`, that is why it is throwing this error. Also, you can not ask a new question by asking it in the answer section. You have to post a new question to get the answer.

Comment: Hi @Rob, now I change the line

Comment: Post a new question, this is different than what I answered.

Comment: hi @Rob this is the new question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60143831/cannot-assign-value-of-type-user-to-type-user)